# Recreating react native Disabling dark mode not working (ios)

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-darkmode

I am trying to prevent app from using dark mode because text becomes white on a white background

These solution for darkmode have not worked for me:

I add this to my Info.plist file: (this does nothing)

```
    <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
    <string>Light</string>
```

I tried this in my AppDelegate.m:   (give me build errors)

```
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        rootView.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `rootView` you should use `self.window`. I fixed it this way:

```
if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
    self.window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
}
```

Comment: is there anywhere specific you put this code that it worked for you. and are there any other things you added?

Answer (score 0):

4 steps to solve this issue if you are using object c.

1. Adding below string and key in info.plist

> ```
> <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key> 
> <string>Light</string>
> ```

2. Open AppDelagate.m
3. Find following line of code [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
4. And just paste below code

> ```
>   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
>   if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
>      self.window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
>   }
> ```